# Find all strictly increasing sequences $\{a_k\}_{k=1}^\infty$ of positive integers such that $\frac{a_{nk}}{a_na_k} \in (1,2)$ for any $n,k>1$

Tags: sequences-and-series

> Find all strictly increasing sequences $\{a_k\}_{k=1}^\infty$ of positive integers such that $\frac{a_{nk}}{a_na_k} \in (1,2)$ for any $n,k>1$.

**Motivation**

First, I was wondering about the strictly increasing sequences of real numbers such that $\frac{a_{nk}}{a_na_k}=1$ for any integer $n,k\ge 1.$ I believe all such sequences look like $a_k=k^\alpha$ for some $\alpha > 0$ (due to Erdős’ result).

Then I started changing the conditions. What if I try to find all the strictly increasing sequences such that $\frac{a_{nk}}{a_na_k}=2$ for any integer $n,k>1$. We can’t deduce $a_1=1$ in this case. Since $a_1$ never participates in $\frac{a_{nk}}{a_na_k}=2$ anyway, it can be any number smaller than $a_2$. Overall, it seems to me that virtually the same reasoning as for the previous question could be made for this case, so $a_k=k^\alpha$ for some positive $\alpha$. But then from $\frac{a_{nk}}{a_na_k}=2$ we get that $1=2$. So such sequences don’t exist.

Now, what if we try the condition $\frac{a_{nk}}{a_na_k}\in (1,2)?$ If we ignore the monotonicity condition then $a_k=2/3$ would work. So something like $a_k={2\over3} + \frac{\sum_{i=1}^k 1/2^k}{10^{100}}$ is fine. There is a lot of such sequences.

Then let us make $a_k$ positive integers, arriving to our main question.

**Hypothesis**

I failed to find an example of such sequence yet. My intuition tells me that if $\frac{a_{nk}}{a_na_k}>1$ then $\frac{a_{nk}}{a_na_k}$ is not bounded. My hypothesis is that no such sequence exists.

**Edit**

Different examples of such sequences have appeared. The hypothesis is wrong. I still wonder if all these sequences can be described in a nice way though.

Comment: By "increasing" do you mean strictly increasing?

Comment: @GregMartin yes, strictly increasing.

Comment: Such sequences certainly can't be bounded, since $a_2\ge2$ and thus $a_{2^m} > 2^m$ for all $m\ge2$.

Comment: @GregMartin I meant $a_{nk}/a_na_k$ is not bounded.

Comment: Consider the greedy sequence, where $a_n$ is chosen to be the smallest integer greater than $a_{n-1}$ such that $a_n/a_da_{n/d} > 1$ for all nontrivial divisors $d$ of $n$. (That sequence isn't in OEIS, fwiw.) Emperically it seems that $a_n/a_da_{n/d}$ is bounded by $1.5$. The largest ratios seem to correspond to certain numbers $n$ that are just greater than powers of $4$.

Comment: @GregMartin It really looks like this approach could work. I’ve calculated a lot of $a_n$, the biggest ratio so far is $19/14$ which is smaller than $3/2$. I’ve noticed that the biggest jumps in $a_n$ value is when $n$ is a power of $2$. Though the ratios are quite small for them.

Comment: Yes, big jumps are caused by a large product $a_da_{n/d}$, so we end up having $a_n=a_da_{n/d}+1$ which causes a small ratio $a_n/a_da_{n/d}$. The biggest ratios occur when $a_n$ is forced to be $a_{n-1}+1$ by monotonicity.

Answer (score 2):

Let $a_n := n^2-1$. Then $\dfrac{a_{xy}}{a_xa_y}\in(1, 2)$ for $x, y\ge2$. In fact

> **Proposition.** $a_{xy} > a_xa_y$

**Proof.**
$$\begin{aligned}
(xy)^2-1 &> (x^2-1)(y^2-1)&\iff\\
x^2y^2-1 &>x^2y^2-x^2-y^2+1&\iff\\
x^2+y^2&>2
\end{aligned}$$
which holds true because $x, y>1.~\square$

> **Proposition.** $a_{xy} < 2a_xa_y$

**Proof.**
$$\begin{aligned}
(xy)^2-1 &< 2(x^2-1)(y^2-1)&\iff\\
x^2y^2-1 &<2x^2y^2-2x^2-2y^2+2&\iff\\
1 &< x^2y^2-2x^2-2y^2+4&\iff\\
1&<(x^2-2)(y^2-2)
\end{aligned}$$
which holds true because $x, y\ge 2.~\square$

Comment: Yes, $n^\alpha-m$ seems to work for any integer $\alpha \ge 2$ and $m$ small enough. Probably $m$ doesn’t have to be a constant, too. So, there is probably a lot of such sequences, built from different ideas, and they are hard to charactarize in a nice way.

Comment: a minor thing, $a_1$ is not a positive integer.

Comment: @Yimin we can set $a_1$ any positive integer smaller than $a_2$. Since $a_2 = 2^2-1=3$ we can take $a_1=1$ or $2$. This number $a_1$ doesn’t participate in the condition anyway. Btw, a simple example $a_n=n-1$ would work too, if we “ignore” $a_1, a_2, a_3$ in a similar way.